# Is it possible to replace a moving transparent area inside video with a image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Have a video with moving transparent rectangle. I want to put up a image in that area. Is it possible using ffmpeg or need to split into frames?

Comment: Define transparent and define moving. Is it one of pixel formats with alpha channel? Do you know how is it moving (i.e. can you predict exact location for each frame)?

Comment: Transparent is fully transparent with opacity as 0 and yes movement can be predicted i think

Comment: If you can write an expression which maps time to rectangle coordinates then you should be able to use `overlay` filter to put the image over this rectange. I doubt it is possible to automatically detect transparent rectangle and cover it in (stock) ffmpeg. There is find_rect/cover_rect filter pair which almost match what you need, but they won't work on alpha-enabled images, nevermind alpha channel alone.

Comment: Thanks for the info can you provide a small example of mapping time and coordinates